What is Ubuntu's version of Disk Management?
I need to find out because I need to see my hard drive space on my laptop.

This question is similar to: How do I find the amount of free space on my hard drive?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

For a more "Disk management" -style display, do
$ upd sudo apt install gparted
to install the gnu partition editor from a terminal.
then run it, also from the terminal by
$ sudo gparted
... or; hit Win/Super key and type gparted (possibly drag the icon to the dash) and click on the icon (it will ask for root access, type your password).

Not Ubuntu version specifically, but Filelight (https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/filelight) shows disk usage in a pretty neat format, see in link: https://apps.kde.org/filelight/
Edit after @FedKad, Gnome version is https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/baobab

Or https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/baobab for GNOME.

... which is installed by default.
